# Issue in configuration of SSRS

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

Windows Server 2003 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2: During installation accidentally I selected "instance for Sharepoint server". Now I want to install the SSRS, in fact I installed it, by adding features from the DVD.

Now from reporting services configuration, I have changed the port from 80 to 120 (with 80 it is not running as well).

When I go to deploy my report (developed in VS) on Report Manager I am getting this error:

```
"This operation is not supported on a report server that is configured to run in SharePoint integrated mode. (rsOperationNotSupportedSharePointMode)"
```

I do not want to run report server in SharePoint integrated mode. I want to run Visual Studio developed report standalone. How can I switch back to non-integrated mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to SQL Server Reporting Service Configuration, you should be able to switch from Sharepoint Integrated mode to native mode. You may have to recreate the ReportServer and Reportservertempdb databases.